# Blazor .net 5 integrity error on 3 files resource blocked

Tags: iis, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I have a simple app blazer wasm project in .net 5 hosted in IIS8.5.
The root of the problem seems to be 3 files are having the following error in console:
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource {offending file here} with a computed SHA-256 integrity [sha-256 number here] the resource has been blocked.
I also get Unknow error occurred while trying to verify integrity.

I have tried cash clearing, and several other remedies. the 3 files are all framework files in _framework, dotnet.wasm, dotnet.timez, icudt_EFIGS.

I tried a fresh boiler plate blazer component project and tried to post it and had the same issue. However a boiler plate ASP.NET Core Web App project seems to work fine

Also, several posts have mentioned startup.cs which my blazer projects do not produce only program.cs. Is there something I do not know about here??

The IIS server hosts rest .net5 and has net 5 hosting package and sdk applied. Also, publishing locally to my IIS produces the same result. However using IISExpress through VS2019 works fine.

I see the Loading... from index.html and get this error in Edge:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwQIW.png)

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: After trying many things, I uninstalled .net 5 and VS2019 and reinstalled them the same problem exists with the standard blazer wasm components project and the same files.

Comment: I have installed everything on my local IIS and rebooted of course.

Comment: I have this identical issue at home and work. I am temporarily using server side blazer.

Comment: Hey, quick question, this issue is consistent across multiple browsers ? I see you are using edge, have you tried with Chrome/Firefox ?

Comment: Chrome was giving me problems when starting and with first letter typed so I finally gave up on all its issues. I never really used Firefox. The tools are good in both Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Hi Joe, I actually just noticed this error as well. I am fairly new to Blazor, and only got it deployed to a server on Friday. Seemed to be working fine, but then I just tested it about half an hour ago, and I'm getting the "resource blocked" errors on the same files as you received. Did you ever find a solution, or did you give up on Blazor?

Comment: I have not found the answer, I simply do not use it. This is a problem for Microsoft. if the standard project from scratch does not work then I do not know what the solution is.

Comment: someone already solved the problem please I need to solve it :(